# How do you measure site load time in IE6?

Tags: performance, optimization, measurement

I'm looking for something similar to [Hammerhead](http://stevesouders.com/hammerhead/). Currently, I write javascript code to test, and I'd rather just use a tool that I can easily share and has a GUI.

**Edit: I'm hoping for something that tracks load events if possible and can easily do repeat tests.**

Comment: More importantly, why are you bothering with IE6?

Comment: @Nerdling, it's not my decision. I have raised this question myself.

Answer (score 1):

**[Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp)** will provide load time information for your pages and all their content.  In addition IE8's developer tools will indicate the load time for you of functions within the page. Just press <kbd>F12</kbd>.

For Fiddler, simply load the page and watch the headers/time results in the right hand frame.

For the IE8 Developer Tools:

1. In the Profiler Tab, click <kbd>Start Profiling</kbd>
2. Reload the page <kbd>F5</kbd> then press <kbd>Stop Profiling</kbd> once loaded and you can see the time to call each function or the entire call tree.

You can also use [**Firebug Lite**](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html) to give IE some Firebug love... just get and log the date at the beginning of the page load... and at the end of the page load... and log the delta.

Comment: But he is asking for IE6 solution.

Comment: True, Keith is looking for an IE6 solution... and Fiddler will provide that (even works for other non-IE browsers) and Firebug Lite will work in IE6 too.  I mentioned the IE8 dev toolbar just as another option if/when IE8 is available. ;-)

Comment: Fiddler's great, and I use it often.

Answer (score 0):

With Firebug Lite, first note that there is a bug with 1.4 on IE8, I had to switch back to v1.3 as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7909733/327074). Secondly you need to include the script link on your `<head>` rather than use the bookmarklet as when you reload the page the bookmarklet form of Firebug lite will disappear. It took me a while to figure out the code for logging the times, which I eventually found on p. 15 of this [Firebug Guide](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/6555469/How-to-use-Firebug)

Put this code in your `<head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.3/firebug-lite.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">console.time('firebug lite');</style>
```

and then put this code at the end of the body section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">console.timeEnd('firebug lite');</style>
```

Note that this will only tell you the load time of your html, css, script and images - not the time for server side code. If you want that you'll need to use Fiddler as per @scunliffe 's answer